# Proces a text file shell script that have numbers and strings

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, text

I have a file in this form:

```
2ThroughputRule.js:128 bw   3545891 3545891 3545891
ThroughputRule.js:128 bw    124776  1835334 1151111
ThroughputRule.js:128 bw    1959606 1876758 2435492
ThroughputRule.js:128 bw    3213333 1765905 2979981
2ThroughputRule.js:128 bw   1985927 2386289 2284143
```

I want a way to process the file so that the shell script can read the first character of each line and if it finds a number copy that number of times that line from next to the number until EOL below.

For instance I have

2ThroughputRule.js:128 bw   3545891 3545891 3545891

The result of this would be

2ThroughputRule.js:128 bw   3545891 3545891 3545891

ThroughputRule.js:128 bw    3545891 3545891 3545891

And If I have

4ThroughputRule.js:128 bw   3545891 3545891 3545891

ThroughputRule.js:128 bw    3545891 3545891 3545891

ThroughputRule.js:128 bw    3545891 3545891 3545891

ThroughputRule.js:128 bw    3545891 3545891 3545891

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I Edited my question thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this program. Save it as `pr.awk`. And run `awk -f pr.awk test.txt`

```
function force_num(x) {return x+0}

match($0, "^[0-9]+") {
    n   = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
    n   = force_num(n)

    rst = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        print rst

    next
}

{
    print
}
```

Comment: But it not always 2 sometimes are diferente numbers, what can I do there?

Comment: @MiguelA.AguayoOrtuño See the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '1; /^[0-9]/{print substr($0,2)}' file
2ThroughputRule.js:128 bw   3545891 3545891 3545891
ThroughputRule.js:128 bw   3545891 3545891 3545891
ThroughputRule.js:128 bw    124776  1835334 1151111
ThroughputRule.js:128 bw    1959606 1876758 2435492
ThroughputRule.js:128 bw    3213333 1765905 2979981
2ThroughputRule.js:128 bw   1985927 2386289 2284143
ThroughputRule.js:128 bw   1985927 2386289 2284143
```

**Command Breakup:**

```
1;                 # prints each record
/^[0-9]/           # if a row starts with a digit
print substr($0,2) # prints from 2nd char onward in next line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` for matching strings and `cut` for removing characters:

```
grep "^[0-9]" file | cut -c 2-
```